# Import / Export error ? Couldn't find a 'component', 'getComponent' or 'children' prop

Tags: react-native, import, export

I need a little help, a fresh look at my code. I made a mistake but can't find where exactly.
I have the error:

> Error: Couldn't find a 'component', 'getComponent' or 'children' prop
> for the screen 'Les commandes'. This can happen if you passed
> 'undefined'. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or mixed up default import and named import when
> importing.

If I understood correctly the other posts which mention this problem, in general it is a syntax or import / export error, and here I must be too soaked with my code, I cannot see it. Could you read it again and give me a hand please?
Thank you so much.

```
App.js: 
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import AppContext from './AppContext';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Authentication from './Screens/Authentication';
const AuthenticationStack = createStackNavigator();
import Splash from './src/components/Splash';
import BottomTabNavigator from './Navigation/TabNavigator';

export default function App() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState({ loggedIn: false });
  const state = { user, setUser };
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 2000);
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <Splash />;
  }

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={state}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {user.loggedIn ? (
          <AuthenticationStack.Navigator>
            <AuthenticationStack.Screen name="Authentication" component={Authentication} />
          </AuthenticationStack.Navigator>
        ) : (
          <BottomTabNavigator />
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Bottomtabnavigator :

```
import React from "react";
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import Orders from '../Screens/Orders';
import Tools from '../Screens/Tools';
import Dashboard from '../Screens/Dashboard';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

import { MainStackNavigator, SettingsStackNavigator } from "./StackNavigator";
import styles from '../assets/styles';
import i18n from '../src/i18n';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{activeTintColor: 'black',
                     labelStyle: {fontSize: 12, color: 'white'}, 
                     style: {backgroundColor: '#F78400'},
                     }}>      
      <Tab.Screen
          name={i18n.t("orders.title")}
          component={MainStackNavigator}
          options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
                return (
                  <Image
                    source={require("../assets/images/orders.png")}
                    style={styles.icon}
                  />
                );
              }
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name={i18n.t("dashboard.title")}
          component={Dashboard}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
              return (
                <Image
                  source={require("../assets/images/dashboard.png")}
                  style={styles.icon}
                />
              );
            }
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name={i18n.t("tools.title")}
          component={Tools}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
              return (
                <Image
                  source={require("../assets/images/tools.png")}
                  style={styles.icon}
                />
              );
            }
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name={i18n.t("settings.title")}
          component={SettingsStackNavigator}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
              return (
                <Image
                  source={require("../assets/images/settings.png")}
                  style={styles.icon}
                />
              );
            }
          }}
        />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default BottomTabNavigator;
```

StackNavigator :

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/stack";
import Authentication from '../Screens/Authentication';
import Activities from '../Screens/Activities';
import Login from '../Screens/Login';
import Register from '../Screens/Register';
import Tools from '../Screens/Tools';
import Dashboard from '../Screens/Dashboard';
import Orders from '../Screens/Orders';
import About from '../Screens/About';
import Terms from '../Screens/Terms';
import Completed from '../Screens/Orders/Completed';
import Current from '../Screens/Orders/Current';
import Details from '../Screens/Orders/Details';
import Settings from '../Screens/Settings';
import Contact from '../Screens/Contact';
import Scan from '../Screens/Tools/Scan';
import Products from '../Screens/Tools/Products';
import Tickets from '../Screens/Tools/Tickets';
import Welcome from '../Screens/Welcome';
import i18n from '../src/i18n';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();


const screenOptionStyle = {
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#F78400",
  },
  headerTintColor: "white",
  headerBackTitle: "Back",
  backgroundColor:'#f7f6f6'
};


const MainStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
   <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptionStyle}>       
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Orders' component = {Orders} options={{ title: i18n.t("orders.title") }}/> 
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Authentication' component = {Authentication} options={{ title: i18n.t("authentication.title") }}/> 
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Activities' component = {Activities} options={{ title: i18n.t("activities.title") }}/> 
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Contact' component = {Contact} options={{ title: i18n.t("contact.title") }}/> 
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Login' component = {Login} options={{ title: i18n.t("login.title") }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Register' component = {Register} options={{ title: i18n.t("register.title") }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Tools' component = {Tools} options={{ title: i18n.t("tools.title") }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Scan' component = {Scan} options={{ title: i18n.t("scan.title") }}/>      
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Current' component = {Current} options={{ title: i18n.t("current.title") }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Completed' component = {Completed} options={{ title: i18n.t("completed.title") }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Details' component = {Details} options={{ title: i18n.t("details.title") }}/> 
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Products' component = {Products} options={{ title: i18n.t("products.title") }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Terms' component = {Terms} options={{ title: i18n.t("terms.title") }}/> 
      <Stack.Screen name = 'About' component = {About} options={{ title: i18n.t("about.title") }}/>      
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Tickets' component = {Tickets} options={{ title: i18n.t("tickets.title") }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Dashboard' component = {Dashboard} options={{ title: i18n.t("dashboard.title") }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Settings' component = {Settings} options={{ title: i18n.t("settings.title") }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Welcome' component = {Welcome} options={{ title: i18n.t("welcome.title") }}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

const SettingsStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptionStyle}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}


export default { MainStackNavigator, SettingsStackNavigator };
```

Orders :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { TabView, SceneMap } from 'react-native-tab-view';
import Current from './Current'
import Completed from './Completed';
import styles from '../../assets/styles';
import i18n from '../../src/i18n';

const FirstRoute = () => (
  <Current style={styles.scene} />
);

const SecondRoute = () => (
  <Completed style={styles.scene} />
);

const initialLayout = { width: Dimensions.get('window').width };

export default function Orders() {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const [routes] = React.useState([
    { key: 'first', title: i18n.t("current.title") },
    { key: 'second', title: i18n.t("completed.title") },
  ]);

  const renderScene = SceneMap({
    first: FirstRoute,
    second: SecondRoute,
  });

  return (
    <TabView
      navigationState={{ index, routes }}
      renderScene={renderScene}
      onIndexChange={setIndex}
      initialLayout={initialLayout}
    />
  );
}
```

As I followed the advice in comment I did :

> console.log({ Orders, Authentication, Activities, Contact, Login,
> Register, Tools, Scan, Current, Completed, Details, Products, Terms,
> About, Tickets, Dashboard, Settings, Welcome });

It gives this:

```
Object {
  "About": [Function About],
  "Activities": [Function Activities],
  "Authentication": [Function Authentication],
  "Completed": [Function Completed],
  "Contact": [Function Contact],
  "Current": [Function Current],
  "Dashboard": [Function Dashboard],
  "Details": [Function Details],
  "Login": [Function Login],
  "Orders": [Function Orders],
  "Products": [Function Products],
  "Register": [Function Register],
  "Scan": [Function Scan],
  "Settings": [Function Settings],
  "Terms": [Function Terms],
  "Tickets": [Function Tickets],
  "Tools": [Function Tools],
  "Welcome": [Function App],
}
```

Comment: where is Lescommandes

Comment: I don't understand where it is. it's the translation of 'Orders' so in fact 'Les Commandes' = i18n.t("orders.title")  the only place it's written is in my translation file.

Comment: to find an invalid import a use a log console.log({
Orders,
Authentication,
Activities,
Contact,
Login,
Register,
Tools,
Scan,
Current,
Completed,
Details,
Products,
Terms,
About,
Tickets,
Dashboard,
Settings,
Welcome
}); to find which import is not correct a React Compoent

Comment: oh, good idea ! thanks, where can I put the command '  console.log({ Orders, Authentication, Activities, Contact, Login, Register, Tools, Scan, Current, Completed, Details, Products, Terms, About, Tickets, Dashboard, Settings, Welcome }); please ?

Comment: I did, and updated my post ! but there is nothing wrong with my files... no ?